# spark-csv fails parsing with embedded html and quotes

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, databricks, spark-csv

I have this csv file which contains description of several cities:

[Cities_information_extract.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrujRmY268Epq9Is7JBS08_yja8TBBwN/view?usp=sharing)

I can parse this file just fine using python [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) or R [read.csv](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) methods. They both return 693 rows for 25 columns.

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to load the csv using Spark 1.6.0 and scala.
For this I am using [spark-csv](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv_2.10/1.5.0) and [commons-csv](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv/1.4) (which I have included in the spark jars path).
This is is what I have tried:

```
var cities_info = sqlContext.read.
format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("header", "true").
option("inferSchema", "false").
option("delimiter", ";").
load("path/to/Cities_information_extract.csv")

cities_info.count()

// ERROR
java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:275)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.getRecords(CSVParser.java:365)
```

Then I've tried using univocity parser:

```
var cities_info = sqlContext.read.
format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("parserLib", "univocity").
option("header", "true").
option("inferSchema", "false").
option("delimiter", ";").
load("path/to/Cities_information_extract.csv")

cities_info.count()

// ERROR
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000
at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.DefaultCharAppender.append(DefaultCharAppender.java:103)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:115)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:159)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:108)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:159)
[...]
```

Inspecting the file I've noticed the presence of several html tags in description fields with embedding quotes like:

```
<div id="someID">
```

I've tried, using python, to remove all html tags using regular expressions:

```
import os
import re

pattern = re.compile("<[^>]*>")    # find all html tags <..>
with io.open("Cities_information_extract.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
    text = infile.read()
    text = re.sub(pattern, " ", text)
    with io.open("cities_info_clean.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        outfile.write(text)
```

Next I've tried again with the new file without the html tags:

```
var cities_info = sqlContext.read.
format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("header", "true").
option("inferSchema", "false").
option("delimiter", ";").
load("path/to/cities_info_clean.csv")

cities_info.count()

// ERROR
java.io.IOException: (startline 1) EOF reached before encapsulated token finished
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:282)
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:152)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:498)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.getRecords(CSVParser.java:365)
at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation$$anonfun$com$databricks$spark$csv$CsvRelation$$parseCSV$1.apply(CsvRelation.scala:304)
[...]
```

And with the univocity parser:

```
var cities_info = sqlContext.read.
format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("parserLib", "univocity").
option("header", "true").
option("inferSchema", "false").
option("delimiter", ";").
load("path/to/cities_info_clean.csv")

cities_info.count()

// ERROR
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100000
at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.DefaultCharAppender.append(DefaultCharAppender.java:103)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:115)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:159)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:108)
at com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser.parseQuotedValue(CsvParser.java:159)
[...]
```

Both python and R are able to parse correctly both files, while spark-csv still fails. Any suggestion for correctly parsing this csv file using spark-scala?

Comment: `.option("quote","")` to prevent the CSV parser from interpreting double-quotes as text field wrappers. I guess Python and R have low-end parsers that don't handle CSV "generally accepted practises"... And your weird file doesn't either.

Comment: Please include sample data here, not in an external service.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter that does not seem to help, Spark raise an error saying that quotation must be at least one character

Comment: Huh? That trick worked (with the Spark parser and Python API) last time I tried... Just try a dummy control character that you are pretty sure will never show up e.g. `'\7'`, then